# Extend generic interface without assigning type?

Tags: java, generics, clojure

I'm trying to read **Clojure** [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure).

There is a IFn interface whose declaration is like :

```
public interface IFn extends Callable, Runnable{
```

I think **Callable** is *generic*. How can IFn know what the type specified here?

```
Interface Callable<V>
```

Comment: It's possible the code is designed to be backwards compatible before generics were implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't. That declaration is basically using the raw type, which is a bad idea. It would be much better to write:

```
public interface Function<V> extends Callable<V>, Runnable
```

That said - I hadn't noticed you were talking about Clojure rather than Java. Given that they're building a bridge between languages, they can do what they want with the type system, to some extent :)

Comment: @PaulBellora.. And I'm sure, you will certainly attend the party if given in `UK` right.. ;)